# Does a germ of a smooth (i.e., $C^\infty$) function at a point of a manifold always extend to a global smooth function?

Tags: differential-topology, manifolds

Obviously this doesn't hold if we replace "smooth" with something like "analytic" or "regular," which are the contexts I'm more familiar with.  And obviously we can't extend a smooth function defined on an arbitrary open set to a global function.  But so far as I can see it seems like we might well be able to extend an arbitrary germ to a global function.

I imagine this is a pretty dumb question from the perspective of someone who knows even a little bit of differential geometry, but I wasn't able to find an answer quickly by Googling.

Comment: Yes, you can always extend it. Take a smooth cutoff function $\varphi$ with compact support contained in an open set where the germ $g$ defines a smooth function, then $g\cdot \varphi$ can be smoothly extended by $0$ to the entire manifold, and has the same germ in $x$.

Comment: These are definitely pivotal to easily show many simple things in a course on manifolds. For example, if $M$ is a manifold, you can define the derivations of $C^\infty(M)$ at a point $p$, and call this the tangent space. Or, you can highlight the local nature of tangent space and define it to be the derivations at $p$ of the germs $\mathcal{G}_p(M)$ of $M$ at $p$. You have an obvious map $\text{Der}_p(C^\infty(M))\to \text{Der}_p(\mathcal{G}_p(M))$. To show this map a surjection, you need some way of an element of $\text{Der}_p(C^\infty(M))$ acting on a function defined only in a neighborhood

Comment: of $p$. You do this by extending the function defined in the neighborhood to the full manifold by multiplying by a bump function.

Comment: Note this is decidely false for complex manifolds and germs of holomorphic functions (a good reason why they are so interesting!).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f$ be smooth around a point of manifold $M$.
Via a map, we have a smooth function on a small open ball in $\mathbb R^n$.
Using a standard construct of a smooth function that is $0$ outside that open ball and $1$ in a smaller ball, we can extend the smooth germ to all of $\mathbb R^n$ and hence to all of $M$ (taking the value $0$ outside tha map we started with).

Comment: Great!  That's exactly what I was thinking, but I got skeptical when I couldn't find such a statement anywhere online.